# Relative Layout Android

Tags: android-layout

I have 6 textviews,3 editboxes and two spinners in a Relativelayout.I am trying to add further editboxes in the app. But the app is not showing the additional boxes.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 


     <TextView  
         android:id="@+id/EditText01"  
         android:text="@string/type1"  
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:textSize="18sp"  
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
     <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/Button01"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>

      <TextView  
         android:id="@+id/EditText02"  
         android:text="@string/type2"  
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
         android:layout_below="@id/EditText01"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
     <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/Button02"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
         android:layout_below="@id/Button01"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>   

     <TextView  
         android:id="@+id/EditText03"  
         android:text="@string/type3"  
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
         android:layout_below="@id/EditText02"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
     <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/Button03"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
         android:layout_below="@id/Button02"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>     

      <TextView  
         android:id="@+id/EditText04"  
         android:text="@string/property"  
         android:layout_below="@id/EditText03"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>     
       <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Button03"
        android:prompt="@string/property"></Spinner>

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/EditText05"
          android:text="@string/propage"
          android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>  
        <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/widget"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/EditText05"
          android:prompt="@string/propage"></Spinner>

          <TextView
          android:id="@+id/EditText06"
          android:text="@string/income"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/widget"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button04" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>   
        <EditText
          android:id="@+id/Button04"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>



     </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

The last editbox or any element further added is not showing in the app.

Please help.

Comment: Do you get any errors when running this? Or they just don't show up?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please update the correct and complete xml file content?

Also, from the GUI designer's point of view, I think these many controls are atrocious on a limited display. Though you have used a `ScrollView`, I would suggest to rethink over your GUI design.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are actually showing but they may be overlapping previous edit boxes. As a test, I replaced all the @strings with sequential numbers as strings and added an extra edit box to the end of your code and it does appear in the layout but overlaps the last one. Try doing the same thing as a test and you will see what I mean. Hope it goes well for you.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Things that strike me as odd about the last EditText:

- It's ID'd as a button. Consider using `Button` if it's a button.
- It has no content, unless it's set programmatically. So `wrap_content`
  on the width will give it a width of 0 (so it's invisible).
- It's in a `RelativeLayout`, but you haven't said which other element it should
  be placed relative to. I think the default is that it'll overlap
  elements, and just go at the top. But because it has a width of 0,
  you won't even be able to see it there.

Hope this helps. Death to RelativeLayout. (Not really, it's useful, but I hate it).